# select element in typeahead with changing ID java- selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have a typeahead drop down. the elements in the list are populated depending upon what I type. All the elements that populate have the ID something like "typeahead-123" where "typeahead" remains same but "123" keeps changing for all the elements' id. Now how do i capture all those elements that are populated in the drop down in a java List.

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@id, 'typeahead')]"));

        for (WebElement option1 : options) {

            if (option1.getText().equals(mychoice))
                option1.click();
            return "Pass";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dev. I just found the answer I will post it below.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer to the question myself. There was an error in my code.

```
  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@id, 'typeahead')]"))
```

this should have been

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'typeahead')]"))
```

I don't what exactly has happened but apparently It solved the problem now I have all the elements of the typeahead dropdown in my List. Thanks.